# Ошибка при добавлении в ICollection<Class> нового элемента

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Вот эта ошибка: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajHWU.jpg
При обращении в поиске к бд с таким же именем вызывает ошибку, но со статической переменной все проходит хорошо. Я так понимаю, проблема именно с item, но не могу понять, какая именно.
P.S. Рекомендация от интеллисенс привести к ToString() не помогла

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю как, но это решило проблему:

```
string fullName = item.ToString();
bus.Drivers.Add(db.Drivers.First(x => x.DriverFullName == fullName));
```